# Where/How does Eclipse store user libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am working on a Java Project in Eclipse. I created a user library called "Spring" and added all the Spring jars to it. My question is, where does Eclipse store this library? Does it copy all the jars into a new directory somewhere on the disk? Or does it maintain information in some configuration file as to which jars belong to the user library?

Comment: What happens if you create a library, and then move one of the jar file of the library elsewhere? Does it still compile?

Comment: @E-Riz: yes. The point of my comment was to make CodeBlue discover that by himself, and thus have the answer to his question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Eclipse does not copy any of the contents of a User Library, it is merely a container with machine-specific absolute paths. The User Library definitions are stored in the workspace; specifically, in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`.

The idea behind a User Library is that it is an abstraction above a collection of JARs that exist outside the project(s); each workspace must declare the contents for itself, since they are external to Eclipse projects.

Comment: This is an approach I cannot say I agree with

Answer (score 10):

You can export them from the workspace where you created them, and import them into the workspace where you want them.

Old: Window -> preferences -> Java -> User Libraries -> import/export

New (not sure what eclipse version this change was introduced): 
Window -> preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> import/export

If that's what you were trying to do (this is how I was led to this webpage)

Thanks @Jorn Vernee for the new version correction

Comment: Note that this is now: Window -> preferences -> Java -> **Build Path** -> User Libraries -> import/export