# Eclipse classpath container - file for defining associated jars

Tags: eclipse, classpath, containers

I have a .classpath file with entries such as

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/current-3d"/>
```

I can then add external user libraries to that container inside eclipse.

But which file is updated once I've done this? I.e. is there a similar xml file that says JAR's x,y + z are associated with the current-3d container?

Answer (score 2):

Right I did actually find the answer, turns out it's the org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file, more info here [Where/How does Eclipse store user libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802964/where-how-does-eclipse-store-user-libraries)

And the specific entry for the jars/user libraries is like so

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.userLibrary.current-3d=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8"?>\r\n<userlibrary systemlibrary\="false" version\="1">\r\n\t<archive path\="C\:/Users/pstatham/javacode/master/RunImported/3d/jgl.jar"/>\r\n</userlibrary>\r\n
```