# Eclipse: User Library Settings Not Saving

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries

I'm working with Eclipse, and I've ran into this weird problem where my User Library settings won't save. Here's the peculiar part: they save for the current *session*, but when I close out of Eclipse and re-open it, the settings are reverted.

I'm trying to remove the follow parts from my library:
[image]

When I remove them, they're gone, but when I reboot Eclipse, they're basically right back here in the library again. It's causing issues because those parts aren't needed/even physically present anymore.

I've tried the following to remedy the issue:

- Deleting my workspace
- Deleting project Classpaths
- Deleting the entire library and re-adding it

I have no idea where the hell this is coming from at this point. That's why I'm here. Pls send help.

Comment: Try exporting the user library. That'll create an XML file. Then delete the user library and exit and reload. Is the library still gone? If so, edit the XML is a text editor, remove the 4 entries you don't want, then import the file. See if that does the trick.

Comment: User Libraries are part of the workspace settings, so if you delete the workspace (or just create a new one using File > Switch Workspace), and the User Library exists in a brand new workspace, it would appear that you have a plugin installed that creates it.

Comment: I'll try that. Is it possible for User Libraries to be part of git repos by chance? It could be carrying over from the pull.

Comment: I exported the XML file and removed the library. It's gone from the Build Path, but reappeared in the User Libraries menu: http://i.imgur.com/Knn3Wru.png

Comment: If you create a new workspace, don't add your project yet, then open Window > Preferences, then Java > BuildPath > User Libraries, the list should be empty. See also: [Where/How does Eclipse store user libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10802964/5221149)

Comment: No dice, I switched workspaces. Completely vanilla, and still: http://i.imgur.com/j92TXCj.png

Comment: Then you have plugins creating those.

Comment: What plugins could even do that? I recently just updated to the latest Eclipse version. Could it be something that came with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this problem, but the way to work around it is by simply making a new library and using it instead. It seems that it'll still update and save new libraries, just this one was locked for some reason.

The way I personally got around it was by putting the JARs into the classpath directly instead of using a user library.